# Image Taking Time before it gets displayed on screen

Tags: react-native

I am trying to reduce the size of the image without reducing the quality so that it gets displayed faster on screen. I have tried a few things but none has been able to work I would love if someone can help me figure this out. Here is my code.
I am trying to reduce the size of the image without reducing the quality so that it gets displayed faster on screen. I have tried a few things but none has been able to work I would love if someone can help me figure this out. Here is my code.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Modal} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import colors, {primaryColor} from '../../../styles/Index';

import {CAMERA, DECLINE, UPLOAD} from '../../icon/svgIcons';
import UploadImageButton from '../../buttons/UploadImageButton';
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import {
  setButtonDisabled,
  propertyId,
} from '../../../redux/propertyManager/uploadSlice';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

import {BASE_URL, JSON_HEADER} from '../../../apis/constants';
import {LoginUserToken} from '../../../redux/limestoneHome/loginSlice';
import Loader from 'react-native-modal-loader';
import Uploadservice from '../../../services/propertyManager/Uploadservice';
import ResponseModal from '../../response/ResponseModal';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function AddPicturePersonal(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getpPropertyId = useSelector(propertyId);
  const loginToken = useSelector(LoginUserToken);
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [responseMessage, setresponseMessage] = useState('');
  const [responseImage, setresponseImage] = useState('');
  const [responseModalVisible, SetresponseModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isImageDisplayed, setIsImageDisplayed] = useState(false);

  console.log('props is hetre ',props)

  const CloseModal = () => {
    SetresponseModalVisible(false);
  };

  const ShowResponse = () => {
    SetresponseModalVisible(true);
  };
  const UploadImage = async passeddata => {
    const requestOptions1 = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: passeddata,
    };
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dgyz39ftx/image/upload',
      requestOptions1,
    );
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log('Cloud===>', data);
    setIsLoading(false);

    const requestOptions2 = {
      propertyId: getpPropertyId,
      imageUrl: data.secure_url,
      progressPercentage: 5,
      screenNumber: 3,
      ScreenName: 'displayimage',
    };
    SendImageToDb(requestOptions2);
  };

  const SendImageToDb = async data => {
    await Uploadservice.AddPersonalPropertyImage(loginToken, data)
      .then(response => {
        if (response == null) {
        } else if (response.succeeded) {
          setImage(data.imageUrl);
          setIsImageDisplayed(true);
  
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ShowResponse();
        setresponseMessage(error);
        setresponseImage(DECLINE);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };


  const cameraFunction = async () => {
  try {
    let options = {
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: false,
    };

    const response = await ImagePicker.openCamera(options);

    if (!response) {
      // User canceled camera capture, do nothing
      return;
    }

    const newFile = {
      name: `${response.filename}`,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      uri: response.path,
    };

    setIsLoading(true);

    const cloudinarydatas = new FormData();
    cloudinarydatas.append('file', newFile);
    cloudinarydatas.append('upload_preset', 'alaw5sfs');
    cloudinarydatas.append('cloud_name', 'dgyz39ftx');
    UploadImage(cloudinarydatas);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
    setIsLoading(false);
    ShowResponse();
    setresponseMessage(error.message);
    setresponseImage(DECLINE);
  }
};

  const SelectImages = async () => {
  try {
    const images = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: false,
    });

    if (!images) {
      // User canceled image selection, do nothing
      return;
    }

    const newFile = {
      name: `${images.path.split('/').pop()}`,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      uri: images.path,
    };

    console.log('Selected image:', newFile);

    setIsLoading(true);

    const cloudinarydatas = new FormData();
    cloudinarydatas.append('file', newFile);
    cloudinarydatas.append('upload_preset', 'alaw5sfs');
    cloudinarydatas.append('cloud_name', 'dgyz39ftx');

    const requestOptions1 = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: cloudinarydatas,
    };

    let response = await fetch(
      'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dgyz39ftx/image/upload',
      requestOptions1,
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    console.log('Uploaded data:', data);

    const requestOptions2 = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: JSON_HEADER(loginToken),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        propertyId: getpPropertyId,
        imageUrl: data.secure_url,
        progressPercentage: 5,
        screenNumber: 3,
        ScreenName: 'displayimage',
      }),
    };

    const Base_Url2 = `${BASE_URL}/property/SetDisplayImageUrl`;

    let response2 = await fetch(Base_Url2, requestOptions2);
    const data2 = await response2.json();

    if (!response2.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

    setImage(data.secure_url);
    dispatch(setButtonDisabled(false));
    setIsLoading(false);
    console.log('Images from DB:', data2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
    setIsLoading(false);
    ShowResponse();
    setresponseMessage(error.message);
    setresponseImage(DECLINE);
  }
};

  const ShowResponseModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        transparent={true}
        animationType="fade"
        visible={responseModalVisible}
        style={{margin: 0}}>
        <ResponseModal
          successText={responseMessage}
          successIcon={responseImage}
          CloseModal={CloseModal}
        />
      </Modal>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{width: props.screenWidth, height: props.screenHeight * 0.7}}>
      <Loader loading={isLoading} color={primaryColor} />
      <Text
        style={{
          fontFamily: 'HelveticaNowDisplay-Bold',
          color: colors.BLACK,
          fontSize: 17,
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginTop: 20,
        }}>
        Building Photo
      </Text>
      {!isImageDisplayed ? (
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}></View>
      ) : (
        <Image
        style={styles.imageContainer}
        source={{uri: image}}
        onLoad={() => {
          setIsImageDisplayed(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
          dispatch(setButtonDisabled(false));
        }}
      />
      )}

      <View style={{marginHorizontal: 20}}>
        <UploadImageButton
          onPress={cameraFunction}
          icon={CAMERA}
          bgColor={primaryColor}
          title={'Snap'}
          color={colors.WHITE}
        />

        <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
          <UploadImageButton
            onPress={SelectImages}
            icon={UPLOAD}
            bgColor={colors.WHITE}
            title={'Upload from gallery'}
            color={colors.BRAND_PRIMARY}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <ShowResponseModal />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    height: '56%',
    backgroundColor: colors.SCREEN_BACKGROUND,
    margin: 20,
    borderRadius: 16,
  },
});

    enter code here
```